# Datatables render is not being hit

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

```
 $("[data-manifest-table]").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        ajax: {
            url: "LoadManifestData",
            type: "POST",
            data: { FilterItem: new FilterItem($("[data-statuses]").val(), $("[data-products]").val(), $("[data-field-reps]").val(), $("[data-states]").val(), $("[data-clients]").val()), __RequestVerificationToken: ReturnAntiForgeryToken() },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("woot");
            }

        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "ClientID" },
            { "data": "TransNo" },
            { "data": "Assigned" },
            { "data": "Due" },
            { "data": "DebtorBusiness" },
            { "data": "Address" },
            { "data": "Appt" },
            { "data": "FieldRep" },
        ],
        "render": function (data, type, row) {
            debugger
            $("td:eq(6)", row).html("<p>hdfg</p>")
        },
    });
```

I have this data tables initialiser and I'm trying to hit the render function becasue I'd like to modify the data. However the render function doesn't get hit. Anyone know why?

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render  seems to suggest that the render is a part of the columnDefs options, not a top level option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be sub-property for `columns` option.

```
"columns": [
    { "data": "ClientID" },
    { "data": "TransNo" },
    { "data": "Assigned" },
    { "data": "Due" },
    { "data": "DebtorBusiness" },
    { "data": "Address" },
    { 
        "data": "Appt", 
        "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
           if(type === 'display'){
               data = "<p>hdfg</p>";
           }

           return data;
         }
    },
    { "data": "FieldRep" }
],
```

See [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) for more information.